# Propagate click event on multiple elements in the same place but not have parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have a question that how can I propagate a click event on 2 elements in the same place but it doesn't have parent-child relationship. For example, I have this html:

```
<body>
    <button id="btn1">BUTTON 1</button>  // position fixed with top/left at 10px
    <div>
        <button id="btn2">BUTTON 2</button>  // position fixed with top/left at 10px (same place of button 1)
    </div>
</body>
```

So in the UI, button 1 and button 2 nearly have the same place, so I want if I click on button 2, the click event is also fired on both button 1 and button 2.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to the click event on your button 2 and then call the click event for button 1 as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I'm using React, both button still have onclick handler.
So I should give button 1 an id, then in onclick handler of button 2, I trigger click event on button 1 as well. Is it correct? Does it have any alternative method for this. Thanks

Comment: @QuocVanTang Yes that is right. This is the most straight forward approach for what you want to do. I don't think you need to figure out any other way. Try it, If you succeed you may accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work if you assigned the same event to the two buttons? or is necessary the other?

```js
function someFuntion() {/* Do something */}
button1.addEventListener('click',somefuntion)
button2.addEventListener('click',somefuntion)
```